# Writing a retryIf operator with Swift's Combine framework

Tags: swift, generics, combine

I'm getting to know Swift + Swift's Combine framework and wanted to check that my attempt at implementing a `retryIf(retries:, shouldRetry:)` operator makes sense. In particular, I'm curious if all the `.eraseToAnyPublisher`s are expected/idiomatic.

```swift
extension Publisher {
    func retryIf(retries: Int, shouldRetry: @escaping (Self.Failure) -> Bool) -> AnyPublisher<Self.Output, Self.Failure> {
        self.catch { error -> AnyPublisher<Self.Output, Self.Failure> in
            guard shouldRetry(error) && retries > 0 else {
                return Fail(error: error).eraseToAnyPublisher() 
            }
            return self.retryIf(retries: retries - 1, shouldRetry: shouldRetry).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Assuming that all the `AnyPublisher`s are ok, when do you want to make your own `Publisher` struct? For example, the regular Combine operator `retry` returns a `Retry<Upstream>` struct rather than an `AnyPublisher`, but I imagine you could implement it along the same lines as the code above, something like:

```swift
extension Publisher {
    func doOver(tries: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Self.Output, Self.Failure> {
        self.catch { error -> AnyPublisher<Self.Output, Self.Failure> in
            guard tries > 0 else { return Fail(error: error).eraseToAnyPublisher() }
            return self.doOver(tries: tries - 1).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how this implements a retry. It just seems to create a publisher chain with a `Catch` at the end. Combine's Retry resubscribes to the upstream for each failure, before passing the failure downstream

Comment: Ah, it's totally possible I've misunderstood the resubscription part! The above version does at least restart the publisher (self) from the beginning on failure (or the right kind of failure with retryIf), and succeeds if the original does, etc. My understanding is that it's actually the `.catch` that handles unsubscribing (and then we resubscribe if we manage to return `self.retryIf`).

Comment: Ah, on second look, i've missed that the other retry is inside the catch, which would only happen in case of a failure. Makes sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate the final `eraseToAnyPublisher`, and thus the heap allocation it requires, by defining your own `Publisher`. For example:

```
extension Publisher {
    func retry(_ retries: Int, if shouldRetry: @escaping (Failure) -> Bool) -> MyPublishers.RetryIf<Self> {
        return .init(upstream: self, triesLeft: retries, shouldRetry: shouldRetry)
    }
}

enum MyPublishers { }

extension MyPublishers {
    struct RetryIf<Upstream: Publisher>: Publisher {
        typealias Output = Upstream.Output
        typealias Failure = Upstream.Failure

        init(upstream: Upstream, triesLeft: Int, shouldRetry: @escaping (Failure) -> Bool) {
            self.upstream = upstream
            self.triesLeft = triesLeft
            self.shouldRetry = shouldRetry
        }

        var upstream: Upstream
        var triesLeft: Int
        var shouldRetry: (Failure) -> Bool

        func receive<Downstream: Subscriber>(subscriber: Downstream) where Failure == Downstream.Failure, Output == Downstream.Input {
            upstream
                .catch {
                    triesLeft > 0 && shouldRetry($0)
                        ? Self(upstream: upstream, triesLeft: triesLeft - 1, shouldRetry: shouldRetry).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                        : Fail(error: $0).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
                .receive(subscriber: subscriber)
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to eliminate the two `eraseToAnyPublisher` calls inside the `catch` body, you will have to give up using `catch`. Instead you will have to implement your own `Subscription`. Implementing `Subscription` is much more complicated, because it has to be thread-safe. However, those calls inside the `catch` body can only happen in the case of an upstream failure, and only one of the calls happens per failure. So if upstream failures are rare, it's probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Exactly the kind of answer I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: If you decide you want to implement your own `Subscription`, you might want to look at either [CombineX](https://github.com/cx-org/CombineX) or [OpenCombine](https://github.com/OpenCombine/OpenCombine) for guidance. These are open-source reimplementations of Combine.