# Swift combine recursive retry

Tags: ios, swift, http, recursion, combine

I would like to perform a recursive once retry with Swift Combine when the server responds with a certain message (in the example a 401 error). The data in that response alters a model, which allows for a single retry.

I wrote a small extension for the result type that was used pre iOS 13

```swift
extension URLSession {
    typealias HTTPResponse = (response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data)
    typealias DataTaskResult = ((Result<HTTPResponse, Error>) -> Void)

    func dataTask(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping DataTaskResult) -> URLSessionDataTask {
        self.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completionHandler(.failure(error))
            }
            completionHandler(.success((response as! HTTPURLResponse, data!)))
        }
    }
}
```

I used this extension to do the following

```swift
class Account {
    enum CommunicationError: Swift.Error {
        case counterOutOfSync
    }

    var counter: Int = 0

    func send(isRetry: Bool = false, completionBlock: @escaping URLSession.DataTaskResult) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://myserver.com/fetch/")!)
        request.setValue("\(counter)", forHTTPHeaderField: "MESSAGE-COUNTER")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [weak self] taskResult in
            do {
                let taskResponse = try taskResult.get()
                if taskResponse.response.statusCode == 401 {
                    if isRetry { throw CommunicationError.counterOutOfSync }

                    // Counter is resynced based on taskResponse.data
                    self?.send(isRetry: true, completionBlock: completionBlock)
                } else {
                    completionBlock(.success(taskResponse))
                }
            } catch {
                completionBlock(.failure(error))
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

You can see the recursive call in the function. I would like to do the same with Combine, but I don't know how to. This is as far as I get

```swift
func combine(isRetry: Bool = false) -> AnyPublisher<Data, Error> {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://myserver.com/fetch/")!)
    request.setValue("\(counter)", forHTTPHeaderField: "MESSAGE-COUNTER")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request).tryMap {
        let response = $0.response as! HTTPURLResponse
        if response.statusCode == 401 {
            if isRetry { throw CommunicationError.counterOutOfSync }

            // Counter is resynced based on $0.data
            return self.combine(isRetry: true)
        } else {
            return $0.data
        }
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you need a recursive function that returns a publisher? Why not just use `Future` with your original `send` method?

Comment: I'm quite new to the Combine framework. Could you elaborate on the `Future`? I believe I do need the publisher indeed. It's async after all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the original `send(isRetry:completionBlock:)`, you can use `Future` to convert it to a publisher:

```
func send() -> AnyPublisher<URLSession.HTTPResponse, Error> {
    Future { [weak self] promise in
        self?.send(isRetry: false) { result in promise(result) }
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

---

Alternatively, Combine already has a `.retry` operator, so the entire thing could be made purely in Combine:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
    .tryMap { data, response in
        let response = response as! HTTPURLResponse
        if response.statusCode == 401 {
            throw CommunicationError.counterOutOfSync
        } else {
            return (response: response, data: data)
        }
    }
    .retry(1)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

This will retry once whenever there's *any* error (not just 401) from upstream. You can play around more to only retry under some conditions (e.g. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63549014/968155))

Comment: Unfortunately, the retry won't work, as the data required to retry is in the response of the HTTP call. I didn't get that to work with the retry function. I never though of promises, but this solves the issue! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Bram, the second example shows how you could get the response data and inspect it (in your case, for a 401 code) to throw an error. Granted, I haven't validated it in code.Are you saying that this example didn't work for you?

Comment: The second one did indeed not work for me as is, but when I used a `tryCatch` it did. But I had to alter the error a bit. `counterOutOfSync(Int)` meaning I can now catch the error and the new counter and use that to create the new call

Comment: @Bram, that's odd that it doesn't work. Maybe there's a difference in your code that's not apparent here. (I used `counterOutOfSync` error just as an example to throw some kind of error)